# PrestaShop Using Default Module Instead of Theme Module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Today I starting design theme for `prestashop` and i'm Beginner on that.
i have a Question about **Theme Module**

i have Some module for my new Theme Located here:

```
prestashop/theme/mytheme/Module
```

and i want customize that for my  new theme.

but the prestashop not using My Module instead using default module Located here:

```
Prestashop/Module/
```

What's Wrong and how to Fix this?

Comment: Do you want to override the modules default behavior? Did you read [this](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingamodule%27sbehavior)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PrestaShop documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingamodule'sbehavior):

> **Overriding a module's behavior**
>
> The modules are usually in the following format:
>
> - `/modules/my_module/my_module.tpl`
> - `/modules/my_module/my_module.css`
> - `/modules/my_module/my_module.js`
>
> Since PrestaShop 1.5, they can and should also be in the following format:
>
> - `/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.tpl`
> - `/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.css`
> - `/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.js`
>
> PrestaShop allows you to override or replace certain front-office module files
>   with new ones within the same theme. The override is governed by the
>   theme: once it contains a `/modules` folder (or more!), PrestaShop will
>   browse its content for files which have the same name and path as
>   those of existing modules, and replace these with the new ones.
>
> This means, for PrestaShop 1.4-compatible modules:
>
> - `/themes/my_theme/modules/my_module/my_module.tpl`
> - `/themes/my_theme/css/modules/my_module/my_module.css`
> - `/themes/my_theme/js/modules/my_module/my_module.js`
>
> Since PrestaShop 1.5, the path is slightly longer
>
> - `/themes/my_theme/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.tpl`
> - `/themes/my_theme/css/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.css`
> - `/themes/my_theme/js/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.js`
>
> In general, the proper path to override a `.tpl`, `.js` or `.css` file
>   depends on the module's own path. That is the reason why if PrestaShop
>   1.5 has to work with a module without a `view` folder, it will need the same override path.
>
> In short, you can keep overriding code in 1.5 just
>   as you did in 1.4.
>
> The new files will be used when the customer loads
>   your shop.
>
> Contrary to the override code that is to be placed manually
>   in the `/override` folder, module overrides are enabled as soon as the
>   module is installed. During installation, overriding code is merge
>   with those already in place (if any), otherwise they are copied to the
>   `/override` folder at the root of the PrestaShop folder.